# Why does sympy integrate introduce imaginary constants when integrating a real-valued logarithm expression?

Tags: python, sympy

> I found the solution while doing research for the question, but I still post the question/answer here. I could not find other resources while searching  online, so I hope this post might help someone in the future.

Hello, I am using `sympy` to compute the integral of a piece-wise defined function.
However, the integration introduces imaginary constants.

### Minimal example

```
from sympy import *
f = interpolating_spline(1, Symbol('p'), [0,0.1,1], [0,10,1000])
r = (ln(20000-f)).simplify()
s = integrate(r)
print('r='+latex(r))
print('s='+latex(s))
```

Which gives

[image: r=\log{\left(\begin{cases} 20000 - 100.0 p & \text{for}: p \geq 0 \wedge p \leq 0.1 \20100.0 - 1100.0 p & \text{for}: p \geq 0.1 \wedge p \leq 1 \end{cases} \right)}]
[image: s=\begin{cases} \text{NaN} & \text{for}: p < 0 \1.0 p \log{\left(20000 - 100.0 p \right)} - 1.0 p - 200.0 \log{\left(100.0 p - 20000.0 \right)} + 1980.69751050723 + 200.0 i \pi & \text{for}: p \leq 0.1 \1.0 p \log{\left(20100.0 - 1100.0 p \right)} - 1.0 p - 18.2727272727273 \log{\left(1100.0 p - 20100.0 \right)} + 181.054613456189 + 18.2727272727273 i \pi & \text{for}: p \leq 1 \\text{NaN} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}]

Why are there imaginary constants in the integral? I vaguely remember something about branch cuts from complex analysis, so it might be related to that?

The origin of the problem formulation is the [Kelly criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion), adapted to loss-exceedance curves.

### Expected result

If I only integrate the first expression, I get a real-valued integral without the constants:

```
In [71]: integrate(ln(20000-100*p))
Out[71]: p*log(20000 - 100*p) - p - 200*log(p - 200)
```

But this result is also strange, as the result will not be defined for `p=0.1`, as `p-200` will be negative. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

## Change integration strategy to `manual`

The constants disappears when using the `manual=True` integration strategy.

```
In [84]: print('r='+latex(integrate(r,manual=True)))
```

[image: r=\begin{cases} \text{NaN} & \text{for}: p < 0 \- 1.0 p - 0.01 \left(20000 - 100.0 p\right) \log{\left(20000 - 100.0 p \right)} + 200.0 \log{\left(20000 \right)} & \text{for}: p \leq 0.1 \- 1.0 p - 0.000909090909090909 \left(20100.0 - 1100.0 p\right) \log{\left(20100.0 - 1100.0 p \right)} - 1799.64289705104 + 200.0 \log{\left(20000 \right)} & \text{for}: p \leq 1 \\text{NaN} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}]

I found this option in the documentation at https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.integrals.integrate